# Ubuntu 22.04 not recognizing connected Bluetooth headphones as audio device

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth, blueman

My JBL Tour One Bluetooth headphones connect to my laptop but are not recognized as an audio device. I have reinstalled all audio packages, tried `pulseaudio` and `blueman` and `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`. The output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` is

```
[    4.514396] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.514420] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.514422] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.514426] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.514428] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.514433] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.745004] Bluetooth: hci0: Legacy ROM 2.x revision 5.0 build 25 week 20 2015
[    4.805824] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-22.50.19.14.f.bseq
[    5.192999] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel BT fw patch 0x43 completed & activated
[    7.778605] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.778612] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.778618] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.065392] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    8.065401] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    8.065407] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```